# Tuning insert into the Oracle database

Tags: oracle

A problem regarding insert into the Oracle data base...I have the code sample(below), this code is inserting 500 records into the db..but it takes 3 minutes to insert 500 records...well as far as I know the tables have indexes, the server is brand new and very fast, I done some test regarding the speed of the network and it's all OK, so my doubt is that my "insert code" is not good...is there a way too like "speed up" the insert or there is something else that I overlooked...so any advice is good...thanks!

This is the "insert" code sample:

```
 myQuery = " INSERT INTO AGR3PL_LINE (IDOC_NUM, SEG_NUM, LINN02, WMLI02, CATN02, LQTY02, IUNT02, TOWT02, WUOM02, DTDR02, ORDL02, LOCN02, DEXP02, DPRO02, NOTS02, " +
                                          " PNUM05, PDES05, PTYP05, PCLS05, IUNT05, SUNT05, PUNT05, ISCF05, SPCF05, SHLU05, SHLF05, CSHL05, BATC05, BARC05, ANAC05, WTSU05, WTBU05, CWIT05, DFSS05) " +
                                          " VALUES (" + Lidoc_num + ",'" +
                                                        SEG_NUM_L + "'," +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("LineNumber") || dr_art_line["LineNumber"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? 0 : dr_art_line["LineNumber"]) + "," +
                                                        WMLI02 + ",'" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemNumber") || dr_art_line["ItemNumber"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["ItemNumber"]) + "','" +
                                                        QuantityInIssueUnit_value + "','" +
                                                        QuantityInIssueUnit_uom + "'," +
                                                        QuantityInSecondaryUnit.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ",'" +
                                                        WUOM02 + "','" +
                                                        DeliveryDate + "'," +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("OrderLine") || dr_art_line["OrderLine"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? 0 : dr_art_line["OrderLine"]) + ",'" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("LotNumber") || dr_art_line["LotNumber"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["LotNumber"]) + "','" +
                                                        ExpirationDate + "','" +
                                                        DateOfProduction + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("Notes") || dr_art_line["Notes"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["Notes"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemCode") || dr_art_line["ItemCode"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["ItemCode"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("Description") || dr_art_line["Description"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["Description"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemType") || dr_art_line["ItemType"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["ItemType"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ItemClass") || dr_art_line["ItemClass"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["ItemClass"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("IssueUnit") || dr_art_line["IssueUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["IssueUnit"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("StockUnit") || dr_art_line["StockUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["StockUnit"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("PurchaseUnit") || dr_art_line["PurchaseUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["PurchaseUnit"]) + "'," +
                                                        IssueToStockConversionFactor.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," +
                                                        StockToPurchaseConversionFactor.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ",'" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ShelfLifeUnit") || dr_art_line["ShelfLifeUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? 0 : dr_art_line["ShelfLifeUnit"]) + "'," +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("ShelfLife") || dr_art_line["ShelfLife"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? 0 : dr_art_line["ShelfLife"]) + "," +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("CustomerShelfLife") || dr_art_line["CustomerShelfLife"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? 0 : dr_art_line["CustomerShelfLife"]) + "," +
                                                        MandatoryLot + ",'" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("BarcodeIssueUnit") || dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"]) + "','" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("BarcodeStockUnit") || dr_art_line["BarcodeStockUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["BarcodeStockUnit"]) + "'," +
                                                        WeightIssueUnit.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," +
                                                        gros_un.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," +
                                                        cat_item + ",'" +
                                                        (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("DefaultStockStatus") || dr_art_line["DefaultStockStatus"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? string.Empty : dr_art_line["DefaultStockStatus"]) + "')";
```

Comment: It might be because of your code, try to print in console (standard output) all inserts you generate. If if will be as slow as when you work with the DB, then you have to optimize you insert generation

Comment: IF the type was CLOB , would that be better ? I am just asking

Comment: Maybe, I have never worked with CLOB..do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this if you've looked at the wait events while it's running and nothing is obvious, is to trace the session. You'll find your answer there. There are a few methods of tracing a session. The one I use (assuming I don't need a logon trigger to enable it immediately) is:

1) Find the spid of the session
  select spid from v$session s, v$process p where s.paddr = p.addr and s.sid = '&sid';
2) Enable oradebug trace (as sysdba)
  oradebug setospid &spid
  oradebug event 10046 trace name context forever, level 12
3) Go find the trace file (check the diag directory. the trace file will have the spid in the name of the file) - in linux typically "ls -lrt" will show it as one of the last files in the list displayed
4) You can run tkprof on the trace file if you want to roll things up. If you want the raw details, review the ".trc" file (it will show everything that happens, the timings, and the order it happened)
5) To disable the trace (if the session doesn't log off)
  oradebug setospid &spid
  oradebug event 10046 trace name context off